# Applying square root inside a function lowers its order when it seemingly should not

Tags: real-analysis

I have these two functions:

$f(x) = x\sqrt{8-x^2}$
$g(x) = \sqrt{8x^2 - x^4}$

If I factor out $x^2$ out of the root in $g(x)$, I will get:

$g(x) = \sqrt{x^2(8-x^2)}$

If I attempt to apply the square root on $x^2$, I will be left with $g(x) = \pm x\sqrt{8-x^2}$, which is either identical to $f(x)$, or its opposite. Both of these results contradict the original function graph ($f(x)$ is red while $g(x)$ is blue. **I offset them by a small value to make them distinct, as they were previously superimposed**):

[image]

I know that if you "externally" simplify *equations*, you lower their order, and therefore alter them. Here, my simplification should not alter the order of the function, or so I thought...

Why is this happening?

Comment: It is evident that $f(0)=0$, contradicting what the graph is showing. Thus I would conclude that the graph is incorrect. It seems that the graph of $f$ has been lifted a bit, but the reason why this has been done is a mistery.

Comment: $\sqrt{x^2}=|x|$. $f(x) \not =g(x).$

Comment: The graph is incorrect because I offset it by a slight margin. The functions were superimposed.

Comment: @PeterSzilas That makes it all clear, but shouldn't you post that as an answer?

Comment: deadsidog.Small matter:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that :

$$g(x) = \sqrt{x^2(8-x^2)} = |x|\sqrt{8-x^2} = \begin{cases} x\sqrt{8-x^2} \; \; \;, \; x\geq 0 \\ -x\sqrt{8-x^2}, \; x<0 \end{cases}$$

Whereas $f(x) = x\sqrt{8-x^2}$ for all $x \in \mathbb R$.

Thus, they are not defined in the same way and this way $g(x)$ will always be positive (which is easy to see anyway, since a rooted value is $\geq 0$).

**Credit to Peter Szilas as well for mentioning the same thing, I hadn't seen the comments earlier when answering.**

Comment: Rebellos.Thanks, very small matter, enjoy reading your posts:)Greetings.

Comment: @PeterSzilas Thanks mate ! What did you mean by "very small matter" ? Greetings from Greece !

Comment: Rebellos.$|x|=\sqrt{x^2}$,is not such a big contribution:)Greetings, from Larnaca(Cyprus)